# Writing raw h264 to mkv

Tags: h.264, mkv

I need a simple code for writing raw h264 data from an video encoder to a mkv file. 
I have been looking into the libmatroska and libebml but there is a lot of code to understand. 
Is there a simple example on how to write h264 to mkv?
Possible using the libmatroska and libebml. 
EDIT: I was probably too tired when I wrote this question, sorry for the poor quality. 
But I need some small c or cpp code that will run on my embedded linux board. 
I tried ffmpeg, bit the shared lib was too large.

Comment: Did you try mkvmerge ?

Comment: did you try `ffmpeg` ?

Comment: #JakobJ, hello. I am also in the same situation. have you found any solution? Thanks.